# Electron Forge issue: "cannot make for linux and target deb"

Tags: npm, deb, electron-forge

I'm once again facing an issue and I can't get out of it...

## The problem

I have an Electron app and I want to build it for linux. So far, I've succeed to create a Windows (Squirrel) build for it, but when I execute the same command from a virtual machine, it gives this error:
`cannot make for linux and target deb: the maker declared that it cannot run on linux`

## Forge configuration

```
module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {
    asar: true,
    linux: {
      target: 'deb',
    }
  },
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {
        authors: 'Sample author',
        description: 'Some description'
      },
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-zip',
      platforms: ['darwin'],
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-deb',
      config: {
        authors: 'Sample author',
        description: 'Some description',
        "name": "app",
        "category": "Games"
      },
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-rpm',
      config: {},
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives',
      config: {},
    },
  ],
};
```

I was expecting to receive a nice .deb file, but I got that error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved!

## Solution

authors and description setting has to be under quotes, like so:

```
"authors":"test",
"description":"some desc"
```

## Full configuration

```
module.exports = {
packagerConfig: {
    asar: true,
    linux: {
      target: 'deb',
    }
  },
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {
        authors: 'Sample author',
        description: 'Some description'
      },
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-zip',
      platforms: ['darwin'],
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-deb',
      config: {
        "authors": 'Sample author',
        "description": 'Some description',
        "name": "app",
        "category": "Games"
      },
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-rpm',
      config: {},
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives',
      config: {},
    },
  ],
};
```